# beforeSend xhr object : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsfiddle, xmlhttprequest

I keep getting this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined 
Where I am trying to apply an "progress" event listener

Why am I getting this error?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#wb_bc_file_field").change(function(){
          var formdata = new FormData();
          formdata.append("video",$("#wb_bc_file_field")[0]);
          // Start Ajax Call
          $.ajax({
            url:"server.php",
            beforeSend:function(xhr){
              xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){

              });
            },
            processData:false,
            contentType:"multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8",

            data:formdata
          }).done(function(){
            console.log("Request is complete.");
          }).fail(function(){
            console.log("Request has failed.");
          }).always(function(){
            console.log("Request has closed.");
          }); // End .ajax
        }); // End .change
      }); // End .ready
  </script>
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6f4Tp/) of the entire script. Since there is no php file it will give an error but thats fine for now.

Comment: I'd like to know, too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error is causing because of calling the upload event even before we start initiating the XHR request.

```
 $.ajax({
        url:"server.php",
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
          xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event){

          });
        },
       ...
```

As in the code we are calling `xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress"` in `beforeSend`. Since we didn't start the request yet, (we are in `beforeSend`) we can't have any `xhr.upload` object. We can solve this by moving code to `xhr` instead of `beforeSend`.

**Note: you need jQuery version > 1.5.1**

```
$.ajax({
  url:"server.php",    
  xhr: function()
   {
   var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
   //Upload progress
   xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
    ...
   }, false);
  return xhr;
 },
```

Here's the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-url-settings