# Jquery $.Post percentage upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, .post

i'm using this ajax method for upload an image and some data of that :

```
$.post("http://-------/uploadFile",{
            img: $("#imageDaRitagliare").cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL(),
            nomeFile : nomeFileInUso,
            nomeFileOrigin : nomeOriginaleFileInUso,
            fileAttuale : $("#img_input").attr("nomeFile"),
            fileAttualePath : $("#img_input").attr("pathfile"),
            fileCanellaAttuale : canCanc
        },function(response){
            var dato = JSON.parse(response);

            $("#img_input").empty().val(dato.nomeOriginaleFile);
            $("#img_input").attr("nomeFile",dato.nomeFile);
            $("#img_input").attr("pathFile",dato.path);
        });
```

this works but i need a way to have a percentage of the upload...
sorry for bad english, i'm italian (:

Comment: http://www.dave-bond.com/blog/2010/01/JQuery-ajax-progress-HMTL5/

Comment: but i have $.post method

Comment: $.post is just a call with $.ajax(), just with the type set as POST. :) Using $.ajax() gives you more control over the data. Here's the link to the api: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Ah okey, thanks a lot :D

Comment: Welcome, I have posted it as an answer too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $.ajax for ajax request since it's have `xhr` in api definition itself. We are accessing the native XHR request and listening for `progress` to show percentage.

```
var data = {
        img:$("#imageDaRitagliare").cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toDataURL(),
        nomeFile : nomeFileInUso,
        nomeFileOrigin : nomeOriginaleFileInUso,
        fileAttuale : $("#img_input").attr("nomeFile"),
        fileAttualePath : $("#img_input").attr("pathfile"),
        fileCanellaAttuale : canCanc
    }

$.ajax({
  xhr: function()
    {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    //Upload progress
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with upload progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
      }
    }, false);
    //Download progress
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        //Do something with download progress
        console.log(percentComplete);
      }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: "/",
  data: data,
  success: function(response){
     var dato = JSON.parse(response);

        $("#img_input").empty().val(dato.nomeOriginaleFile);
        $("#img_input").attr("nomeFile",dato.nomeFile);
        $("#img_input").attr("pathFile",dato.path);
  }
});
```

Comment: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of undefined. on : XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23140054/beforesend-xhr-object-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-addeventlisten Bad luck. It's unanswered.

Comment: if that is unanswered how that can help me? ahah :)

Comment: I've updated the answer. You could use it if you are using jQuery version > 1.5.1